# Adding string tags to each value of jQuery Sparklines plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, sparklines

I'm implementing [jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about) plugin for a web app I'm developing. I want to add tags to the pie chart values so when you hover over that specific chart you will se "**Automotive** (25%)" instead of the default int value "**1** (25%)".

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Here is the code I have:

```
    $(function(){
        var myvalues = [10,8,5,7,4,4,1];
        $('#sparkline').sparkline(myvalues, {
            type: 'pie',
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px',
            sliceColors: ['#5d3092', '#4dc9ec', '#9de49d', '#9074b1', '#66aa00', '#dd4477', '#0099c6', '#990099'],
            borderWidth: 7,
            borderColor: '#f5f5f5'
        });
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: see in docs version 2 -  tooltipPrefix  A string to prepend to each field displayed in a tooltip, or the tooltipFormatter function ,

Comment: Awesome! I will post the correct code as the answer :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A better alternative to using tooltipPrefix or writing your own formatter is to use tooltipFormat and tooltipValueLookups instead to map the index in your array of values to a name:

```
    $(function() {
    var myvalues = [10,8,5,7,4,4,1];
    $('#sparkline').sparkline(myvalues, {
        type: 'pie',
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        sliceColors: ['#5d3092', '#4dc9ec', '#9de49d', '#9074b1', '#66aa00', '#dd4477', '#0099c6', '#990099'],
        borderWidth: 7,
        borderColor: '#f5f5f5',
        tooltipFormat: '<span style="color: {{color}}">&#9679;</span> {{offset:names}} ({{percent.1}}%)',
        tooltipValueLookups: {
            names: {
                0: 'Automotive',
                1: 'Locomotive',
                2: 'Unmotivated',
                3: 'Three',
                4: 'Four',
                5: 'Five'
                // Add more here
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a link to the Sparkline docs for the above methods: http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#tooltips

Comment: for bar chart spakline  use the link http://jsfiddle.net/gwatts/ckabau8u/ for the reference

Comment: Thumbs up for an `offset` placeholder.

Answer (score 11):

I also use bootstrap, I ran into this issue where I couldn't see the tooltip:

Globally setting box-sizing to border-box causes tooltip to be displayed incorrectly. This can be fixed by the following css after bootstrap. This may become an issue as box-sizing is more frequently used.

```
.jqstooltip { box-sizing: content-box;}
```

Here's the link. 
https://github.com/gwatts/jquery.sparkline/issues/89

Comment: This is the fix if your using Bootstrap.  Verified

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working example of a pie charts with custom labels

http://jsfiddle.net/gwatts/ak4JW/

```
// jsfiddle configured to load jQuery Sparkline 2.1
// http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/
// Values to render
var values = [1, 2, 3];

// Draw a sparkline for the #sparkline element
$('#sparkline').sparkline(values, {
    type: "pie",
    // Map the offset in the list of values to a name to use in the tooltip
    tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}} ({{percent.1}}%)',
    tooltipValueLookups: {
        'offset': {
            0: 'First',
            1: 'Second',
            2: 'Third'
        }
    },
});
```